# How to change drupal password on localhost (xampp)?

Tags: php, drupal, passwords, xampp

I have a Drupal website on my computer.

I forgot its password and I don't know how to recover it.
I can't send emails in my computer or localhost.

I read a lot of webpages about resetting the password in Drupal on localhost, but not working.

Comment: Why don't you configure `XAMPP` to send emails? Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/4193263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset you password use this command:

```
UPDATE users SET pass='$S$Cd059Vsxc8berFeg6hspaa7ejx2bSxyUisvCbT4h9o8XIgSUtPKz' WHERE uid=1;
```

This password is: password

To sent emails from XAMPP, use SMTP module: https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file "new_password.php" (or with any other name) inside your drupal folder and access it using browser. It will generate one way encrypted hash password for you.

```
<?php
  define("DRUPAL_ROOT", getcwd());
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . "/includes/bootstrap.inc";
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
  require_once "includes/password.inc";
  echo user_hash_password("123456");
  die();
  menu_execute_active_handler();
?>
```

When you run this code in browser it will show you hash password like

```
$S$D95YW4EejaUDPq5nZ7Z2Ljx1Ud4wlN1iTMQdAKton70JcQpCZmrG
```

Now you need to update your database table using above hash. Open your database using PHPMyAdmin or Workbench and run the below query.

```
UPDATE users SET pass = '$S$D95YW4EejaUDPq5nZ7Z2Ljx1Ud4wlN1iTMQdAKton70JcQpCZmrG' WHERE uid = 1;
```

Now you can access drupal using username as "admin" and password as "123456". Make sure you update password after login to the admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the localhost password using the `drush`

drush upwd --password="yourpassword" username

for eg: `drush upwd --password="sweety" pragya`

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to reset password using drush .
 Just type 
`drush uli`.
This will give you one time password reset url for Admin.

Something like `http://default/user/reset/1/1428579639/O1Rs12HxYZV7rrMUR7xuXhg9RDvsk9OFZ1-nVCoSVWU`

Replace `default` with your actual drupal URL and paste it in browser it will ask for new password.